# Looking for a simple text Template Engine to generate Query

Tags: javascript, node.js, couchbase

I am using couchbase which has a feature called N1QL which is similar to SQl but for couchbase doc store. My problem is that if i want to query by several fields i have to create a template for each possible option which can get out of hand.
Before i take a stab at building my own template based system i was wondering if there is a basic text template engine which supports stuff like if and ets me pass values.

This is part of a sample query

```
FROM Contacts AS f
 LEFT JOIN Contacts AS t
 ON t._type ="tract_info" AND ANY b IN t.tract_id SATISFIES b = f.tract END
 WHERE f._type="farm" and f.tract IN $3 $4
 order by f.PropertyAddress.streetName, TONUMBER(f.PropertyAddress.houseNumber)
```

where i would like to pass something like `{25,0,(12,25,35),“and ARRAY_COUNT(f.phones) > 0 and ARRAY_COUNT(f.emails) > 0”}`

Any idea or pointesr would be great

Comment: I could not completely understand your question. Could you please reframe it?

Answer (score 0):

The SDK already has a way to construct queries programmatically. You can see an example of this in the demo app, here:

https://github.com/couchbaselabs/try-cb-java/blob/5.0-updates/src/main/java/trycb/service/Airport.java#L36

This is Java code, of course. But the JS SDK should have something similar.